# Validating latitude/longitude in Laravel validation regex rule - preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found

Tags: php, regex, laravel, latitude-longitude, laravel-validation

I am trying to validate latitude/longitude in Laravel 5.4 project with custom regex rule (based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22007205/2332336)

```
// Create validation
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    // ...
    'lat' => 'required|regex:/^[-]?(([0-8]?[0-9])\.(\d+))|(90(\.0+)?)$/',
    'long' => 'required|regex:/^[-]?((((1[0-7][0-9])|([0-9]?[0-9]))\.(\d+))|180(\.0+)?)$/'
], [
    'lat.regex' => 'Latitude value appears to be incorrect format.',
    'long.regex' => 'Longitude value appears to be incorrect format.'
]);

// Test validation
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

When this runs, I am getting the following error:

> preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found

I've tried this also;

```
    'lat' => 'required|regex:^[-]?(([0-8]?[0-9])\.(\d+))|(90(\.0+)?)$',
    'long' => 'required|regex:^[-]?((((1[0-7][0-9])|([0-9]?[0-9]))\.(\d+))|180(\.0+)?)$'
```

Now I get this error:

> preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found

What is the correct syntax to validate lat/lng in laravel via custom regex rule?

Comment: Looks like you have to use an array?

Comment: It might be more simple to validate by range like:
'lat' => 'between:-87,89',
'long' => 'between:-180,180',

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Is it possible that the pipes are the problem? See, for example, [Laravel 5.4 - Validation with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577045/laravel-5-4-validation-with-regex). I see that your regexp has a pipe character in it. Try separating the rules into an array instead of using the pipe here: `required|regex`

In the second example, the first `^` is interpreted as the character that starts the regex string, so it expects a final `^` to match it.

Comment: It was the pipe problem, i've solved it like this: `'lat' => ['required','regex:/^[-]?(([0-8]?[0-9])\.(\d+))|(90(\.0+)?)$/'],
            'long' => ['required','regex:/^[-]?((((1[0-7][0-9])|([0-9]?[0-9]))\.(\d+))|180(\.0+)?)$/']`

Comment: The above regex is confirmed working for coordinate validation, thanks!